# $(..) location picker is not a function - Error on Jquery Location Picker OnChanged Event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, jquery-plugins, error-handling

I am using [Jquery location picker](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/) in asp.net mvc - On Page Load It is pointing fine on default location and no error is generated on Browser Console But When I Change the Marker Location on Map To Other Location then it givens error $(..).locationpicker is not a function

I am having error at the following jquery line -

```
 var addressComponents = $(this).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
```

**HTML CODE**

```
      <div class="form-group">

                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Country</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, "-- Select Country--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, "State", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("States", null, "-- Select State --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, "City", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cities", null, "-- Select City --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            </div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     <input type="hidden" name="DataID" value="@ViewBag.BusinessID" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="us2" style="width: 550px; height: 400px;"></div>
            <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery CODE -**

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places'></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/locationpicker.jquery.js"></script>        
<script>

        $('#us2').locationpicker({
            location: { latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125 },
            radius: 100,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us2-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us2-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us2-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us2-address')
            }, onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                var addressComponents = $(this).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
                //  updateControls(addressComponents);
                console.log(addressComponents);
                console.log(addressComponents.length);
                for (var key in addressComponents) {
                    if (addressComponents.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        //alert(key + " -> " + addressComponents[key]);

                        if (key == "postalCode") {
                            $('#ZipCode').val(addressComponents[key]);
                        }
                        if (key == "country") {
                            $('#country').val(addressComponents[key]);
                        }
                        if (key == "stateOrProvince") {
                            $('#States').val(addressComponents[key]);
                        }
                        if (key == "city") {
                            $('#Cities').val(addressComponents[key]);
                        }


                    }
                }
            }, oninitialized: function (component) {
                var addressComponents = $(component).locationpicker('map').location.addressComponents;
                //   updateControls(addressComponents);
            },
            enableAutocomplete: true

        });


</script>
```

Comment: Wrap the code inside $(document).ready( function.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi ok let me try

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I tried it but after placing it under $(document).ready map stopped showing so it removed it

Comment: It is giving no error on page load it gives error only after chaged event occurs

Comment: @Steve - Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x272696x/ I don't see any issue in the code. Are you sure the jquery files are being loaded correctly ?